# Redefining `undefined` in `window` object

Tags: javascript

I wonder is it possible to create function that would have a name "undefined" in order not get error when calling undefined()?

I've tried to do this way

```
var obj = {};
obj[undefined] = function() {};
obj.undefined();
```

It works, however, I want to do something like this:

```
window[undefined] = function() {};
```

But my browser (Chrome 44) doesn't allow to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: *doesn't allow to do it.* - Why? Does it show any error?

Comment: I'm struggling to see how this would just lead to JS code failing with even less visibility than it normally has,

Comment: @thefourtheye, no. It ignores the override.

Answer (score 2):

Because `undefined` is a non-writable property of `window` object.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "undefined").writable
false
```

Since it is not writable, it simply ignores the write operation.

Quoting [MDN documentation on `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#Description),

> In modern browsers (JavaScript 1.8.5 / Firefox 4+), **`undefined` is a non-configurable, non-writable property** per the ECMAScript 5 specification. Even when this is not the case, avoid overriding it.

Comment: Is there any way to change its descriptors?

Comment: @arm.localhost No, you cannot. For other properties, you can normally use `Object.defineProperty` to refine.

Comment: I did it a fast research and didn't find any methods of changing non-configurable properties. But, I think there are some workarounds and hacks :) (it is JS)

Comment: @arm.localhost [As per the ES5 Spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.1.3), `undefined` should not be writable. So overriding that means non-compliance to the spec :(

Comment: I am now even more confused... According to MDN, ```undefined``` is a type rather than an Object. but consoling ```Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "undefined")``` gives the output ```{value: undefined, writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: false}``` which shows that undefined is an Object?? Also, MDN states that undefined is the property of gloabal object. but when i print ```window``` i don't see undefined as a property. As i am just starting out with JS, I am not really able to wrap my head around this concept.